# Form doesn't show controls, It shows an empty form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

`Details` form doesn't show anything even when it is called from the `Welcome` form.

here's all the code (*its like login-signup project*):

**Details Form**

```
namespace D
{
    public partial class Details : Form
    {
        public string dtext1;
        public string orform = string.Empty;
        public string orform2 = string.Empty;
        public string orform3 = string.Empty;
        public string orform4 = string.Empty;
        public Details(string incomform,string incomform2,string incomform3,string incomform4)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            orform = incomform;
            orform2 = incomform2;
            orform3 = incomform3;
            orform4 = incomform4;
        }

        public Details() 
        {
        }

        private void Details_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = orform;
            textBox2.Text = orform2;
            textBox3.Text = orform3;
            textBox4.Text = orform4;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

**Welcome Form**

```
namespace D
{
    public partial class Welcome : Form
    {

        public Welcome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Details Det = new Details();
            Det.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

any help/advice would be really a big legit help

Comment: I posted an answer for you, also I removed form1 and form2 from your question because they are not required and also they have made your question hard to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with your `Details` form constructor that you didn't call `InitializeComponent();` in it. Change it to this:

```
public Details() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

All designer generated codes including your controls definition and properties and layout is in `InitializeComponent` and it should be called in your form the constructor to add controls to your form and perform layout.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are calling this method:

```
this.Close();
```

So like that you are closing the application, so try like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Details h = new Details();
        h.ShowDialog();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

I would suggest not to call methods like `Det`, because depending on which libraries you are using, Det might be something else's name, so that might break your program.

Comment: Thank you so much man...But it's still no use Form"Details" wont show instead! a Form that is Blank appeared (sorry for my grammar)

Comment: Probably you have done something wrong while styling the Form "Details"